# How do I isolate unmanaged code crash in .Net Process

Tags: .net, crash, isolation

.Net Console Application depends on COM objects that tend to crash from time to time in very unpredictable way. Application simply closes with no reason at all: no logs, no exceptions (`catch` block doesn't work at all), no event logs, nothing about the error occured.

How can I isolate native crashes? Will AppDomain approach save me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It will not, this is native code bombing.  You'll need to isolate it in its own process.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute.WrapNonExceptionThrows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimecompatibilityattribute.wrapnonexceptionthrows.aspx)?

Alternatively, a catch block without a type should catch [non CLS-compliant exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264489%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), i.e:

```
try
{
    // Code here.
    // Maybe a COM call here.
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Managed exceptions.
}
catch
{
    // non CLS-compliant exceptions.
}
```

Using a seperate AppDomain will most likely not work depending on why exactly your application is getting killed off in the first place as [unhandled exceptions will still kill the entire process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and currently your exception is unhandled as you haven't caught it.

Alternatively you could use the COM objects within a separate process and use inter process communication between the two. This would isolate the problematic code into it's own process which you can then restart / use as needed without your main process being killed off.

Comment: The OP says he doesn't get an exception.  In fact he says this approach doesn't work at all.  Reread the question.

Comment: @Inuyasha The OP says that the `catch` block does not work at all, he does not say whether he was doing `catch (exception ex) { }` or just `catch { }`, he also didn't mention whether wrapping is enabled or not. Either of which could solve his problem if he is getting non CLS-compliant exceptions.